# How do I determine connection quality on my PS3?

Tags: psn

Is there an option or is there a site that will let you rate connection quality and tell you if there is some particular mechanism (like an unavailable port) that is not working?

Is there some app at the PSN store, is there a site that I can visit throught the PS3 internet browser?

Games are getting more robust, but the downside is that the symptoms of poor connectivity is more subtle and give various odd gameplay behavior instead. The fact that exploits and hacks are easily confused with glitches doesn't make the matter easier.

However, I am taking average of four minutes in joining Assassins creed brotherhood multiplayer waiting for hooking up with other players. While online videos show others barely having the time to sit straight in the chair before the game starts.

Just to be clear, I am not looking for general advice on my home network like wired vs wireless or how to configure the router. I am looking for some service or test that will tell me wether the connection is up to speed.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the cross menu bar on your PS3 and select Settings>Network Settings>Internet Connection Test, it will display your download/upload speed, as well as a few other things of interest.

You could also go to [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net/) for something similar on your computer.

If there's a big difference between speeds on the PS3 and your computer, perhaps there's something wrong with the hardware.